# Submit a Listing Form and Redirect To PayPal

Tags: forms, paypal, ads, payment, subscription

I need help please.

I have a WordPress business directory that the subscriber completes the listing form and clicks submit which goes to admin for approval to advertise their business on my website. Please see link

https://mercatoposto.com/submit-listing/category/

I have added PayPal plugin for them to pay after listing, clearly shown on the user account page, however this is totally ignored and they logout.

Is there a way that when the form is submitted to admin, the subscriber is redirected to PayPal gateway to pay? I want it that they cannot logout of the website until they complete the transaction.

Appreciate a responsive code please, many thanks.

Regards,
Tina

Answer (score 0):

> I want it that they cannot logout of the website until they complete the transaction.

Sure, just install a WordPress plugin that forces a browser logged into your site to remain open and displayed on the user's device until they make a PayPal payment....

What you are asking for makes no sense at all.

On approval of something unpaid for, send them an email informing them that what they submitted won't provide any service until they make a payment, and in such an email have a link to where they can make that payment.

---

To your earlier question of wanting to redirect them after they submit a form, that is also possible. It'll have to be done from whatever the WordPress page is after they submit that form. Of course, just because you redirect them does not mean they will pay.